# Código realizado en Windows sirve en Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

tengo una pregunta que capaz es muy básica.
Si realizó un sistema Backend(SpringBoot) y Frontend(Angular) en Windows, y otro programador utiliza Linux, habrá algún error al ejecutar el sistema en Linux, ya que el sistema se desarrolló en Windows.
Disculpen mi ignorancia y muchas gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Que yo sepa esos frameworks trabajan con javascript. Cómo javascript es un lenguaje interpretado, el código sería compatible

Comment: podria darse el caso de que en tu aplicacion windows hagas referencia a archivos con rutas en formato windows? si es asi (que lo dudo, porque hablamos de frontend) entonces podria darse uno de los casos de error, ya que las rutas se interpretan de distinta manera en cada S.O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kenny ha día de hoy ya casi cualquier lenguaje moderno es compatible con multiplataforma.
PHP, Node, Net core, Javascript, Ruby on rayls, etc... Todos estos lenguajes de programación ya los han realizado de tal manera que se puedan correr tanto en windows como en linux como en mac.

Antiguamente si que había problemas de compatibilidades pero hoy en día buscando un poco por internet veras que eso ya no ocurre.

Comment: muchas gracias Jordi